# (Integration) Question on U-Substitution Mistake

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

For context, I was playing with this integral recreationally:
$$\int{20\sin(\frac{x^2}{35})}dx$$
I decided to try u-substitution, and got the following:
$$u=\frac{x^2}{35}\space,\space du=\frac{2x}{35}dx\space,\space x=\pm\sqrt{35u}$$
$$\frac{35}{2x}du=dx\space,\space \pm\frac{35}{2(\sqrt{35u})}du=dx$$
Substituting $u$ for $\frac{x^2}{35}$ and $\pm\frac{35}{2(\sqrt{35u})}du$ for $dx$, I rewrite the integral as:
$$\pm\frac{20*35}{2\sqrt{35}}\int{\sin(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}}du$$
Just to check, I evaluated both from $0$ to $\pi$ absolutely in Mathematica, and obtained:
$$|\int^{\pi}_{0}{20\sin(\frac{x^2}{35})}dx|\approx5.8725 \space , \space |\pm\frac{20*35}{2\sqrt{35}}\int^{\pi}_{0}{\sin(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}}du|\approx105.88$$
Getting different numerical approximations, I assume I did something wrong. So my question is what was my mistake?

Please keep in mind I don't need to symbolically solve this integral, I just wish to better understand symbol pushing.

Comment: @Atmos bijectivity is not at all a requirement for $u$-substitution

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot to change the bounds....
$$
\frac{20\times 35}{2\sqrt{35}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi^2}{35}}\frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{u}}du \approx 5.872
$$

Comment: Oh boy do I feel silly. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Chloe it's all good! I make many mistakes like this all the time too!